# Can the BS option cause data inconsistency with dd?

Tags: linux, dd

I have a laptop partition (truecrypt) backed up with dd since it's impossible to back it up with anything else but do a raw bit by bit copy like:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=imagefile.img
```

I can of course successfully restore this as well but the restore time is long with the default bs (512).

Would it cause any inconsistency if I would increase the BS size to let's say 1MB? The machine have 8Gb memory, reading 1mb or 10mb or 100mb into memory before writing it out to the disk shouldn't matter but I'm curious what will it do when it reaches the end of the image file and the end of the partition. Wouldn't it try to overwrite data on the next disk area??

Let's say at the last read only 512bytes left in the image, wouldn't it try to write out that 512bytes+the remaining 0.00048828125 Mbyte to the disk?

```
dd if=imagefile.img of=/dev/sda1 bs=1M
```

Thanks

Comment: No, it wouldn't.

Comment: `dd` won't write out more than it read, unless you're using `conv=sync` as an option. Note that you're creating the image from `/dev/sda` but in your example you're restoring to `/dev/sda1`, so that obviously won't work as expected :-)  Apart from that: Linux won't allow you to write past the end of a partition e.g when writing to `/dev/sda1`, so you don't have to worry other partitions will be touched. That's what they're partitions for.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, let's find out. Make some random data

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/rand1Mx10.dat bs=1M count=10`

Copy it various ways:

```
$ dd if=rand1Mx10.dat of=1Mx10copy_3M.dat bs=3M status=progress
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0196387 s, 534 MB/s

$ dd if=rand1Mx10.dat of=1Mx10copy_1M.dat bs=1M status=progress
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0176384 s, 594 MB/s

$ dd if=rand1Mx10.dat of=1Mx10copy_nbs.dat  status=progress
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.083932 s, 125 MB/s

$ dd if=rand1Mx10.dat of=1Mx10copy_333.dat bs=333 status=progress
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0649439 s, 161 MB/s

$ dd if=rand1Mx10.dat of=1Mx10copy_pi.dat bs=314159265 status=progress
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0103404 s, 1.0 GB/s
```

Out:

```
$ shasum /tmp/*.dat
9303b1c6a72ab0ed4c6d7f091ec9f16b8c5ecda1  /tmp/1Mx10copy_1M.dat
9303b1c6a72ab0ed4c6d7f091ec9f16b8c5ecda1  /tmp/1Mx10copy_333.dat
9303b1c6a72ab0ed4c6d7f091ec9f16b8c5ecda1  /tmp/1Mx10copy_3M.dat
9303b1c6a72ab0ed4c6d7f091ec9f16b8c5ecda1  /tmp/1Mx10copy_nbs.dat
9303b1c6a72ab0ed4c6d7f091ec9f16b8c5ecda1  /tmp/1Mx10copy_pi.dat
9303b1c6a72ab0ed4c6d7f091ec9f16b8c5ecda1  /tmp/rand1Mx10.dat


$ ls -l *.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 10485760 Feb 15 09:15 1Mx10copy_1M.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 10485760 Feb 15 09:16 1Mx10copy_333.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 10485760 Feb 15 09:14 1Mx10copy_3M.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 10485760 Feb 15 09:15 1Mx10copy_nbs.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 10485760 Feb 15 09:17 1Mx10copy_pi.dat
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mike mike 10485760 Feb 15 09:11 rand1Mx10.dat
```

Everything checks out. `dd` reports the same number of bytes. File size matches. Hashes line up. `dd` knows to stop writing once it runs out of input file, or runs out of space. Let's do one more to be thorough, we'll make a filesystem which is a touch too small:

Make a 10MB file:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/myfs.img bs=1M count=10
```

Turn it into a filesystem:

```
$ mkfs.ext4 myfs.img
```

Mount it (use root)

```
$ sudo mount myfs.img /mnt/myfs
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /mnt/myfs
```

Look at space (it's less than the file size due to metadata, inodes, etc:

```
$ df -h /mnt/myfs 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0      8.7M   92K  7.9M   2% /mnt/myfs
```

Write 10MB to it:

```
$ dd if=rand1Mx10.dat of=/mnt/myfs/1Mx10copy_pi.dat bs=314159265 status=progress
dd: error writing '/mnt/myfs/1Mx10copy_pi.dat': No space left on device
0+1 records in
0+0 records out
8269824 bytes (8.3 MB, 7.9 MiB) copied, 0.205584 s, 40.2 MB/s
```

Runs out of space but it isn't going to "write beyond" because from the kernel's perspective, there is nowhere else to write to. It's not the same file as before (since we truncated it):

```
$ shasum /mnt/myfs/1Mx10copy_pi.dat 
2c7330b75e1fa573de4d13ce3c7cbcad8139454d  /mnt/myfs/1Mx10copy_pi.dat
```

But when we clone our whole "device" (note the way bigger block size)

```
$ dd if=myfs.img of=myfs2.img bs=1G status=progress
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 0.0255448 s, 410 MB/s
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/myfs2     
$ sudo mount myfs2.img /mnt/myfs2
$ shasum /mnt/myfs2/1Mx10copy_pi.dat
2c7330b75e1fa573de4d13ce3c7cbcad8139454d  /mnt/myfs2/1Mx10copy_pi.dat
```

We get a pristine copy.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do would be to run an MD5 hash on all files prior to the backup and then do a restore and check the MD5 hashes against them.

```
dd if=imagefile.img of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M
```

You can even try 16M or larger.  Just make sure to keep checking the MD5 hashes occasionally.

Data inconsistency can be caused by a number of different things, I doubt the BS option itself would cause them, usually it depends on what the machine is doing during the backup that might cause data inconsistency.